# Can't make offline page work in progressive web aoo

Tags: reactjs, typescript, progressive-web-apps, workbox

Techs: React, TS, Tailwind CSS

So, I was learning how to make a PWA & I'm successful in making one. But I can't active the **offline** page.

I saw a bunch of tutorials & read articles that are out of date.

I followed this latest info related to this from the following link but still can't make my **offline.html** page work :
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/managing-fallback-responses/#offline-page-only

File which has the above code: https://github.com/mzs21/weather-app/blob/main/src/App.tsx#L22

Offline.html file: https://github.com/mzs21/weather-app/blob/main/public/offline.html

Github: https://github.com/mzs21/weather-app

Live: https://weather-app-mzs.netlify.app/

TIA.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In PWA to work with Offline files, you can follow the below-mentioned steps:-

1. Open the offline page on the website and go to the network tabs in the dev tools.
2. Now change to offline mode and refresh the offline page.
3. In-network tab you will see some files, rather chunk files getting called.
4. One by one copy those file URLs from the header and past them inside your service worker in the cache array.
5. Your cache.addAll will have this type of file which I have mentioned below.

```js
'/static/css/8.74e12705.chunk.css',
'/static/css/main.f4039512.chunk.css',         
'/static/js/8.fe897f0b.chunk.js',
'/static/js/main.bcf94194.chunk.js',
'/static/js/0.e2c58f2d.chunk.js',
'/static/js/1.5d470210.chunk.js',
'/static/js/4.9e9f39a1.chunk.js',
'/static/js/12.4eb8aa89.chunk.js',
'/static/js/16.9e2c1c31.chunk.js',
'/offline.html',
```

Comment: Can't even access the offline.html

Comment: First access offline page in online mode and see the network tab and add URL for all the chunks and then try to access it in offline mode

Comment: Can't even access it.

Comment: @Snigdho I am facing the sam issue, any update to resolve it?

Comment: @SwapRenge Nope, apparently gave up.